# Unable to deploy EAR using wldeploy Weblogic

Tags: weblogic

I want to deploy my EAR in weblogic server using wldeploy. Following is the command used.

```
<taskdef name="wldeploy" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy">
    <classpath>
    <pathelement location="C:\Oracle\WebLogic\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Deploying Applications  -->
    <!-- <target name="deploy" depends="module_create"> -->
    <target name="deploy">
    <wldeploy action="deploy"
              name="${ear.file.name}"
              source="${ear.install.dir}/${ear.file.name}"
              user="${wls.username}"
              nostage="false"
              password="${wls.password}"
              verbose="true" debug="true"
              adminurl="t3://${wls.hostname}:${wls.port}" targets="${server.name}" />
    </target>
```

On doing so i get the following error.

[wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():445] : Initiating deploy operation for app, atg_production.ear, on targets:

[wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():447] :    atg_production

[wldeploy] Task 2 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application atg_production.ear on atg_production.

[wldeploy] dumping Exception stack

[wldeploy] Task 2 deferred: [Deployer:149026]deploy application atg_production.ear on atg_production.

[wldeploy] Target state: deploy deferred on Server atg_production

**[wldeploy] java.rmi.RemoteException: [Deployer:149145]Unable to contact 'atg_production'. 
Deployment is deferred until 'atg_production' becomes availble.
***[wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.UnreachableHostException.writeReplace(UnreachableHostException.java:47)
[wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[wldeploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[wldeploy]     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteReplace(ObjectStreamClass.java:1032)
[wldeploy]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1107)*

Not sure why do I have an RMI exception. Could any one please tell what could the cause of this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of {wls.hostname}. Looks like this is atg_production. Check if you can accesses atg_production from the machine where you are trying to run this wldeploy. Based on the exception, either the machine is not reachable (no connectivity , firewall issues etc) or the weblogic on atg_production is down.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your admin server is running. What is the value of ${server.name}? Based on the output, it is atg_production. Please make sure the server you deploy to has the server name as "atg_production".